# how to resize just one side of polygon tool?

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

How can I select walls of room(room image is in jpg format) with polygon tool? I am trying to resize just one side of polygon .

I have tried resizing one side with ctrl + mouse but its not working

I want to select wall of room image with polygon tool

```
   <html>
<head> </head>
<body> 
<h1> There is no code to add here for adobe illustrator 

</body>
</html>
```

Can I select the walls from jpg room image with ploygon tool?

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + mouse only works on Adobe Photoshop, [this is the tool that you need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxP1U.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with Direct selection tool 
choose point in a side of polygon and change that.
good luck